# Is there a way to run the code analysis function separately? Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis

Is there a way to run the code analysis function separately? in visual studio

Can I execute Visual Studio's code analysis function separately?

If that doesn't work, can you run code analysis via cmd?

Answer (score 0):

"If that doesn't work, can you run code analysis via cmd?" 
-> Yes u can.
assming u have a solution u want to analyze u need to get the files within the solution.
via MSBuildWorkspace u can get the projects of your solution. from there u have access to all the documents. 
with those documents u can create the compilation. with that compilation u have access to the CompilationWithAnalyzers (for that u need an assembly with all of your diagnosticanalyzers).
with that CompilationWithAnalyzers u can get the diagnostics of your analyzers.